# skip teardown when testcase fails

Tags: python, nosetests

Is there any way to skip teardown method too if any of the testcase fails.
I tried -x option but it skips only testcases and not teardown.
I am sure there has to be some way as the testcase fails , the setup on which it was executed needs to be there for debugging.

Comment: Before you try stopping teardowns: are you sure your testcase is properly defined? If you have valid reasons for a huge, complicated test-case, please disregard (I am guessing out of the blue here), but gut-feeling tells me the problem may indeed be with the test, not with having to stop a teardown.

Comment: Stopping teardown if testcase failed will provide the setup in that state and would be easier to debug . Is there any other way?

Comment: I am more at home in java, which has really good IDE's and UnitTesting-systems, but doesn't your system provide a way to set breakpoints for debugging? I am running on the assumption that python cannot be THAT different :).

Comment: ofcourse debugger can help. I was just curious to know if there is a way in nosetests itself:)

Comment: Ah, I see :). In that case, carry on stopping teardown ^^.

Comment: I'm also looking for exactly this. Did you find a clean solution?

Comment: not realy, will post it if i get one

Comment: I wish to do something similar. When running tests individually I would like the option to skip tearDown (to leave system ready for debugging).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32347427/1314077 this may be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to somehow achieve it is this way:

```
class TestClass():

    def setup(self):
        print "I am in setup"

    def teardown(self):
        if getattr(self, 'is_fail', False):
            return
        print "I am in teardown"

    def test_fail(self):
        print "I am in test fail"
        try:
            assert False
        except AssertionError as e:
            setattr(self, 'is_fail', True)
            raise e

    def test_pass(self):
        print 'I am in test pass'
        try:
            assert True
        except AssertionError as e:
            setattr(self, 'is_fail', True)
            raise e
```

If you run it you will get:

> `I am in setup` 
>   `I am in test fail`
>   `I am in setup`
>   `I am in test pass`
>   `I am in teardwon`

But notice that it is not such a good practice to catch AssertionError in this case. You should consider searching for a nose plugin or write one yourself.